# How to get-aduser when you have the users LDAP string?

Tags: powershell, ldap

If I have the users DSN

```
/LDPA://server.domain/cn=john smith, ou=users, ou=acme, ou=com
```

how do i get the User? I think its with

```
get-aduser -LDAPFilter "cn=john smith, ou=users, ou=acme, ou=com"
```

but it doesn't work and the documentation doesn't actually show it used this way. Anyone know how to get the User when provided with this info?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was close, but there was no example on the link above. This was how I eventually got this working.

```
# displayName
$DisplayName = $parameter1.SubString($loc1+1, $loc2-($loc1+1))
# -searchBase 
$OULocation = $parameter1.SubString($loc2+1,($parameter1.length-1)-$loc2)
# get the user
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter {displayName -eq $DisplayName} -SearchBase $OULocation
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: edited to include how i got the parameters. which does answer the question.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. The question is how to search using an (btw invalid) LDAP DN and you answer by searching with `displayname` and a searchbase (OU to search in).. Two completely different things. If this is what you wanted, then update the question to match it. You have references to `$loc1`, `$loc2` and `$parameter1` without them ever being created. What are they? Add sample values in your question and answers so they are reproducable and easy to understand for future readers who may look at this for a solution to a similar problem. :-)

Comment: so tell me Frode, how to search using a valid LDAP DN. since nobody else did and you seem to know?

Comment: First you need to get a valid LDAP DN (because the sample in the question isn't close). A valid DN looks like `CN=Frode F,OU=Testusers,OU=SomeOU,DC=internal,DC=acme,DC=com`. When you have this, you can simply use `Get-ADUser -Identity "CN=Frode F,OU=Testusers,OU=SomeOU,DC=internal,DC=acme,DC=com"`

Answer (score 0):

Extremely close but the domain portion of your LDAPFilter wouldnt be OU, it would be DC, see the following page for more info...

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell-get-aduser-filter.htm

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sorry, but as you can see i did answer his question prior and then said for more info refer to such and such page. his query is right except the domain portion, as i stated